# Resolving "GET /blog HTTP/1.1" 404 2065 (Python Django Tutorial: Full-Featured Web App Part 2 - Applications and Routes)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a48xeeo5Vnk&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=2 on YouTube.

I am getting the error message `[24/Oct/2019 22:41:41] "GET /blog HTTP/1.1" 404 2065`.

```
urls.py

from django.urls import path
from .import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    ]



views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResposne('<h1>Blog Home</h1>')

# Create your views here.


urls.py - django_project1

"""django_project1 URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

I have tried to clear my history, cache and restart the server. I tried to find any typos I may have made. Other questions on SO about similar issues are either not referencing the tutorial series I am following or are referencing a later episode of the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is 1:1 your code then you should check:

```
return HttpRe**spos**ne('<h1>Blog Home</h1>')
```

Because you have typo here ;)
I also use app_name frequently in my app urls, like so:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'myApp'
urlpatterns = [ ... ]
```

Also please check if your app is added in settings.py, in 'INSTALLED_APPS' list

Comment: This got an upvote but which suggestion turned out to be the problem?

Comment: He has 'HttpResposne' instead of HttpResponse in his code - it is a typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this because I always use '/' for home page and never use only a space in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('/', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    ]
```